# Pivot Unpivot Additional Column

Tags: sql, pivot

If I would have some table for example :

```
   [Speed] [Ram] [Whatever] [Other]
      S1    R1     W1        O1
      S2    R2     W2        O2
      S3    R3     W3        O3
```

And I would like to have all like this.

```
[Chr]     [Value]
Speed      S3
Ram        R3
Whatever   W3
Other      O3
```

---

So I write following code:

```
SELECT value
FROM
   (SELECT speed, ram
   FROM pc where code=3) p
UNPIVOT
   (value FOR xxx IN
      (speed, ram)
)AS unpvt
```

Problem is when I want to add my second column [chr]

```
    SELECT value, chr <---- This does not work 
        FROM
           (SELECT speed, ram, whatever, other
           FROM pc where code=3) p
        UNPIVOT
           (value FOR xxx IN
              (speed, ram)
        )AS unpvt
UNPIVOT
           (chr FOR zzz IN
              (speed, ram, whatever, other)
        )AS unpvt
```

I have no idea how to add another column to this code. Please any advice.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Why do you need two `UNPIVOT`? Where is the `code` column in your example data?

Comment: Just suppose there is code column in DB. I dont need 2 unpivot . I just dont know how to add chr column in such situations.

Comment: [You need this?](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/eb53b/5)

Comment: What if The type of column "whatever" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
SELECT Chr, Value
  FROM
(
  SELECT t.*
    FROM pc t
   WHERE code = 3
) s
UNPIVOT
(
  Value FOR Chr IN (Speed, Ram, Whatever, Other)
) p
```

Output:

```
|      CHR | VALUE |
--------------------
|    Speed |    S3 |
|      Ram |    R3 |
| Whatever |    W3 |
|    Other |    O3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6663/3)** demo